# How can I pass an image that is uploaded by user to another div, when press a button?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

In my code first div is for showing the image. Second div for uploading ani image and third div will show the preview. I want to display the uploaded image in the first div on button press.

```
<html>
<body>
   <div id="imgspace1" class="container">
        <!-- image preview div -->
        <div id="image_preview1"><img id="previewing1" src="" /></div>
   </div>
<!--image upload part-->
   <div>
   <form id="uploadimage" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       <input type='file' onchange="readURL(this);" />
   </form>
   </div>
<div id="image_edit" class="container">
   <img id="image_preview" src="#" alt="Upload Image"/> </div>
<div>
<input id="confirm_button" type="button"  value="Confirmn" onclick="('')"/>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: also add your Jquery code if it is related to `jquery`

Answer (score 0):

If your prime concern is displaying a preview of the image you may use [EZDZ](https://github.com/jaysalvat/ezdz)
js library.Then you just have to add an image tag and import the .js and .css files and you will be able to see the preview and then upload it by ajax.

Answer (score 0):

```
function readURL(input) {
    if ( input.files && input.files[0] ) {
        var FR= new FileReader();
        FR.onload = function(e) {
             $('#previewing1').attr( "src", e.target.result );
        };       
        FR.readAsDataURL( input.files[0] );
    }
}
```

This code will read the uploaded image in file element.

Answer (score -1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#confirm_button").click(function{
    var preview = $('#image_preview').attr('src');
    $("#previewing1").attr("src", preview);
  });
});
</script>
```

You can copy the src of third div image to first div image. And confirm button will be . You can write this unction in javascript also with onclick event.